# Yes/No column in SQL 2018 studio

Tags: sql, postgresql, boolean, sqldatatypes

Can anyone explain how to create a yes/no column in SQL Studio 2018? `BOOL` or `bit(1)` are not working.

```
Create Table Diseases
(
    P_ID int not null, 
    NameofDis varchar(100),
    DateofDis date,
    Condition bit(1), 
);
```

Comment: @dvo, Is `2` really `false/no`? I'm not familiar with PostgresSQL, so I can't say. But for reference, please confirm this. Thank you!

Comment: @WEI_DBA brain fart haha. You're correct. It's 0, not 2. Too late to update my comment though. I will repost it as answer

Comment: Guys,I have already solved it by using bit not 1 or 2. Sorry for basic question :)

Comment: Use a `boolean`  column

Comment: What exactly is SQL 2018 studio?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using `BIT` instead of `BIT(1)`. This will create the column as a yes/no field aka `true`/`false` field where `1` is yes/true and `0` is `no`/`false`.

Your code:

```
Create Table Diseases(
    P_ID int not null, 
    NameofDis varchar(100),
    DateofDis date,
    Condition bit 
);
```

Comment: @Qulu Quliyev: you should use a proper `boolean` type for that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name why is that?

Comment: Because that's what a `boolean` is for. A "bit" is something different. With a boolean column you can use proper boolean expressions, e.g.: `where condition` or `where condition = false`. Neither of those work with `bit`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sure, readability is nice. However, a `BIT` takes less storage and can still be used in a `where` by doing `where condition = 1`. I don't believe either way is wrong.

Comment: No, `bit` is a single byte as well, just like boolean. The general rule of thumb is to use the data type that matches what you want to store in there. Use `date` for dates, `text` for strings, `integer` for numbers and `boolean` for boolean values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple `BIT` datatype or you can use `BOOLEAN` data type like this

```
Create Table Diseases(
P_ID int not null, 
NameofDis varchar(100),
DateofDis date,
Condition BIT, 
);
```

or

```
Create Table Diseases(
P_ID int not null, 
NameofDis varchar(100),
DateofDis date,
Condition BOOLEAN, 
);
```

Comment: `boolean` is the much better choice.

Comment: Yes boolean is a better choice for true/false because bit datatype isn’t actually to this kind of data.